# docker container stop denied by apparmor

Tags: permissions, docker, apparmor

I use docker 19.03.13 installed from snap on my 20.04 machine. Long time all works well but now I can't stop containers that I have started as unprivileged user. Stopping as root as also not possible.

Following error message is printed out if I try to stop containers:

```
$ docker container stop p3e
Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: p3e: Cannot kill container 03e287d: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:392: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

After debugging some time I found `apparmor` as root cause. Sending `TERM` to `runc` will be denied by apparmor.

```
[77212.968533] audit: type=1400 audit(1614332881.638:148): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="docker-default" pid=243676 comm="runc" requested_mask="receive" denied_mask="receive" signal=kill peer="snap.docker.dockerd"
```

I found the corresponding profile in `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.dockerd` but my apparmor skill are currently limit I would say.

Now my question. How can I get rid of denying my stop action? I'm only interested in fixing the profile. Deactivation of apparmor isn't an option!